# TeXlive update - how do I permanently set the path?

Tags: texlive, installing, paths

I updated to texlive 2015 and it works, as does tlmgr. I can't read dvi's anymore (I'm assuming this is a related problem and if not will deal with it later).
I have to set the path every time I run a new terminal, otherwise I get 'command not found' when I try to run tlmgr or latex.
Do I need to do something additional in the terminal in order to set the path permanently? I am running the following command in terminal and it is working:

```
PATH=/usr/local/texlive/2015/bin/x86_64-linux:$PATH
```

Comment: This mostly depend on what kind of TeX Live you installed and the operating system.

Comment: On Debian, add this to your `.profile`: `export PATH="/usr/local/texlive/2015/bin/x86_64-linux:$PATH"`. When you log in again (or do `source ~/.profile`) the path will be set. You can test by entering `tex --version` and seeing if you get an error message.

Comment: Other systems use different configuration files, but in any case you have to put this somewhere where your shell will read it every time you log in, and add this folder to the search path (the set of directories the system looks in to find executable files).

Comment: Okay so (mint 17) I added the path to etc/environment, and now cannot boot. I have to then boot into ubuntu, change the file under su back to the default in order to be able to boot again. Something tells me that means the directory is wrong, but I have the exact directory, i can navigate to it and everything. Do I have to set environment variables somewhere else?

Comment: Update - adding it to the .profile worked. I guess changing /etc/environment was a bad idea

Comment: glad you got it working but this is off topic, setting the path would be needed for any program not installed in the standard bin directories so is purely an operating system question unrelated to tex.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle It may be unrelated to Tex, but I have this exact problem every time I install a new TexLive. At the end of the installation it says to add that directory to your PATH. I do, but when I `sudo tlmgr ...` it tells me "command tlmgr not found". `echo $PATH` confirms the directory is set and it should be right, because I copied and pasted it from the output of the installation. I don't understand what I'm doing wrong but I always have to run `sudo /full/path/to/tlmgr` in order to make it work.

Comment: @Andyc  you need the path to be set for both you (so you can use tex and root so sudo commands work) where are you setting it? what does `sudo echo $PATH` say? (or rather sudo su, then echo $PATH)

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I guess you are right (as always) :-) `sudo echo %PATH` does show the right path being there, but `sudo su` and the `echo $PATH` does not. So now the question would be: how do I set it for `root` too, but that I can google.

Comment: OK, so I googled that. It turns out it's not as easy as one may think. But that's not the point. In one question on AskUbuntu specifically on this topic, it says that you are actually supposed to change the ownership of the /usr/local/texlive directory to your user and then not use sudo. Can anyone confirm this? By default the /usr/local directory and everything underneath it are owned by root. Is it safe to change it?

Comment: @Andyc I have the same problems with the path setting (Linux Mint). My only 'solution' is using `sudo /full/path/to/tlmgr path add` after installation to create links in `/usr/local/bin`.