# What is the easiest way to set path of updated(new version) texlive installation?

Tags: installing, paths

I can remember that I might get a easy solution, but now I can't find this in this site.

```
$ whereis pdflatex
pdflatex: /usr/bin/pdflatex /usr/bin/X11/pdflatex /usr/share/man/man1/pdflatex.1.gz
```

But, updated installation location is

```
/usr/local/texlive/2018/bin/x86_64-linux
```

Some solution

[Set PATH to use the current TeX Live bin directory](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/379878/set-path-to-use-the-current-tex-live-bin-directory)

[TeXlive update - how do I permanently set the path?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/266969/texlive-update-how-do-i-permanently-set-the-path)

[How do I configure the paths for TexLive2011 to work on my system with TexWorks 0.5?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/27316/how-do-i-configure-the-paths-for-texlive2011-to-work-on-my-system-with-texworks)

Comment: What operating system are we talking?

Comment: @JosephWright Ubuntu

Answer (score 7):

Open your .bashrc script and write the following lines at the end:

`PATH=/usr/local/texlive/2018/bin/x86_64-linux:$PATH; export PATH MANPATH=/usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/doc/man:$MANPATH; export MANPATH INFOPATH=/usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/doc/info:$INFOPATH; export INFOPATH`

And then you should be good to go.

Comment: That is actually insufficient. If you start your editor from a menu it will never see the addition from bashrc. Make sure to also add it to `.profile`, log out and in again (.profile is only read at login)

Comment: I am sorry I should have mentioned that. Either put it in your .bash_profile too or just source your .bashrc in your .bash_profile. Both works fine for me.

Comment: Remember not all systems use bash_profile

Comment: If I am correct, `.bashrc` is a config file read by BASH each time one connects to "interactive" shells (terminals or pseudo-terminal in the case of a terminal emulator running under a windowing system etc.) It means adding to `PATH` will be repeated each time the terminal is open. I think `.profile` is the correct config file for PATH-like definitions in Ubuntu.

Answer (score 0):

I think,

```
tlmgr path add
```

is the command to add the binaries to the `PATH`. It is not quite commended to add `.../texlive/bin/x86_64-linux` to the path directly as `biber` and other tools might be installed in other locations.

Source: http://tug.ctan.org/info/tlmgrbasics/doc/tlmgr.pdf

[image]